# if not gcc -static then shell says 'no such file'

Tags: linux, shell, gcc, android-ndk

I do not know why, but the ([Android ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)) shell says `no such file or directory` when I compile with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` **without** the `-static` option, and then attempt to execute the native executable. This is the `no such file or directory` you get when the shell knows the file exists at that path, but doesn't want to give the user permission to know the file exists. (e.g. you can check with `chmod 4755` which returns no error message).

If I compile **with** the `-static` option then the program executes normally.

Why does this happen when compiling without the `static` option?

Comment: It might be the problem with finding the helper for shared executables (`/lib/ld-linux.so` or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you link statically everything the program needs will be built in. There are no
dependencies to libraries on your device, so it will run perfectly. Bad is the size
of this programming style (huge)!

If you leave out the -static your compiler assumes dynamic linking, but without some
magic you link against (Linux)-glibc: crash!
Search for "native C on Android" tutorial on the net, please. They explain all
the (horrible) linker-stuff you nee to link against Android)-glibc aka "Bionic".

Good luck
may the sources be with you
Martin